# Get the CCK field value using dbquery

Tags: entities, database

I have a content type called user registration under this one cck field called regid. i would like to fetch the entered values of this particular field through programmatically probably by using dbquery() functions and print it. Anyone guide me how to achieve it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically get field values](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27293/programmatically-get-field-values) - i know it's not about db_query, but you wrote *probably*. And field_get_items is much better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little example, how to make requests in Drupal 6. You may change table name and field name and it should work for you.

```
$query = db_query('SELECT n.nid, regid.regid_FIELD_VALUE
   FROM {node} AS n
   JOIN {regid_FEILD_TABLE_NAME} AS regid ON regid.vid = n.vid 
   WHERE n.type = %s AND n.status = %d, $your_node_type, 1);

$result = array();
while($node_data = db_fetch_object($query)) {
  $result[] = array(
    'nid' => $node_data->nid,
    'regid' => $node_data->regid_FIELD_VALUE,
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you please guide me how to done the same thing in drupal 7.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12515/entityfieldquery-vs-db-select