# Get data from database

Tags: 7, database

I'm running Drupal 7 site on WAMP Server!

I'm using below code in a custom block to get data from the database :

```
$result = db_select('event', 'x')
  ->fields('x', array('address'))
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAll();
foreach ($result as $value) {
  print_r ($value);
}
```

***Event*** is the name of node we use

Every time I try to reload the page, I get this message :

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

When I check WAMP PHP error log, there is nothing in it about it !

Any idea ?

**Update :**
Now is see I get this error :

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'drupal.event' doesn't exist: SELECT x.address AS address FROM {event} x; Array ( ) in eval()
```

I understand that it mean it can't find the table, but why ? I found it like that in every example on the internet !

Comment: You should look at what database tables are provided for nodes and look at the API for db_select, etc... to see what it actually does.

Comment: That is not how you search in the nodes content. Check this link: https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708

Comment: @juankvillegas THX, it helped me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Above error is Drupal specific error, to get more details about this error you need to go to Drupal Logs. You can access Drupal Logs by navigating to "**Admin => Reports => Recent Log Messages**". These logs are provided by [Database logging](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/dblog) Module in Drupal Core.

**Updates:**

> **Event** is the name of node we use

In Drupal [Nodes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/nodes-content-types-and-fields/about-nodes) data is stored into **node** table and not table named with content type. Check out [getting started guide about node](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/nodes-content-types-and-fields). *You've to check **node** table to get all nodes where **type** is event.*

To fetch nodes you can use EntityFieldQuery API. Check example on [How to use EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708). And to fetch any fields value, check **[Programmatically get field values](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/27294/678)**.

Comment: Thx for your answer :p

Comment: I updated my question, may I ask you to have a look please ?

Comment: @Soheyl, I've updated answer. You're querying into wrong table. To fetch nodes basic data you need to query node table, where nodes basic data such as nid, title, type are stored.